# Inserting data into many to many

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table `tags2` with fields `tag_id` and `name`. I have a junction table `tag_map` with fields `tag_id` and `vid_id` that connects table `tags2` to table `video` (via vid_id).

When I insert a new tag for a `vid_id`, I delete all my entries in `tag_map` for that `vid_id`, if there was only one entry in `tag_map` for that `tag_id`, I also delete that tag in table `tags2` to prevent ghost entries (tags entries without a corresponding tag_map entry).

I then proceed for each tag when inserting to check if that tag exists in the `tags2` table. If it does, I get its `tag_id` and I insert an entry into the `tag_map` table. If it doesn't I insert into both tables. **Is there a better way to do this?** One guy mentioned that I should have foreign keys on both `tags2` and `tag_map` but I still don't know how I can check to see if a tag exists or not in table `tags2` so I can get its `tag_id` and match it with the entry into `tag_map`.

```
foreach($variable as $tag) {

    $sql = 'SELECT *, COUNT(tags2.name) as cnt
FROM tag_map
JOIN tags2 ON tags2.tag_id = tag_map.tag_id
JOIN video ON video.vid_id = tag_map.vid_id
WHERE tags2.name=?';
$stmt_tags2 = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result=$stmt_tags2->execute(array($tag));
while ($row = $stmt_tags2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $cnt=$row['cnt'];
    $exist_tag_id=$row['tag_id'];
}

$id=md5(uniqid());
$tag_id=md5(uniqid());

if ($cnt==0){
    $sql="INSERT into tag_map (id,vid_id,tag_id) VALUES (?,?,?)";
$stmt16 = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result=$stmt16->execute(array($id,$vid_id,$tag_id));
    $sql="INSERT into tags2 (tag_id,name) VALUES (?,?)";
$stmt16 = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result=$stmt16->execute(array($tag_id,trim($tag)));
}
else {
$sql="INSERT into tag_map (id,vid_id,tag_id) VALUES (?,?,?)";
$stmt16 = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result=$stmt16->execute(array($id,$vid_id,$exist_tag_id));
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi there let me try and stop you and just tell you how to make a really good tags database model. Looks like you are almost there but just need a little hand.

Tables.
Tags
tag_id (Primary)
name (VARCHAR)
status TinyInt

Tag_rel
tag_id (Primary)
Object_type (Primary)
object_id (Primary)
status TinyInt
(add index for object_type,object_id)

Ok so Tags table stores your tags - you already have this.
Tags_rel stores your tags to video relationship. You will notice that I've used object_type and object_id because when you next come to say do photos object_type = 1 could be videos and object_type = 2 could be photos and so on and so on.

Now for your pseudo code.

post tags
UPDATE tag_rel SET status = 0 WHERE object_type = x and object_id = y

-normally explode

for each tag {
does tag exist in tags table
no - insert and get id
yes - get id.
UPDATE tag_rel SET status = 1 WHERE object_type = x and object_id = y AND tag_id = id
}

Yeah that would be my best way of doing it and I think almost an industry standard, little unsure about this query.

SELECT *, COUNT(tags2.name) as cnt
FROM tag_map
JOIN tags2 ON tags2.tag_id = tag_map.tag_id
JOIN video ON video.vid_id = tag_map.vid_id
WHERE tags2.name=?

I hope I've helped here.
Richard

Comment: So basically you are saying I should keep the way I am inserting, but modify my tag_map table to have a status field for more flexibility? A database expert said I should add foreign keys on tag_id field but then stopped helping me lol so I am unsure about that. Any thoughts on that? Thanks for your time Richard.